# Quisiera saber alguna forma de usar Hack, el lenguaje de programación de Facebook

Tags: facebook, hack

Estuve leyendo algo sobre [Hack](http://hacklang.org), el nuevo lenguaje de programación de Facebook.

Pero no vi en la [documentación](https://docs.hhvm.com) la forma de implementarlo. O sea, una vez creado mi primer programa en Hack:

```
<?hh
echo 'Hello World';
```

No encontré explicado en la documentación cómo ni donde usar ese programa, si en una aplicación interna de Facebook o dónde... o si se usa combinado con código de PHP, ya que es bastante parecido a este lenguaje.

Comment: En la máquina virtual de Hack. HHVM - http://hhvm.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De acuerdo al [tutorial](https://docs.hhvm.com/hack/getting-started/getting-started), los pasos a seguir son:

1. Instalar HHVM y Typechecker
2. Configurar Typechecker
3. Escribir tu primer programa Hack
4. Ejecutar el Typechecker
5. Ejecutar el código en HHVM